# Google Places API - status: "REQUEST_DENIED" on mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using the Distance Matrix Service to get the walking duration between two points. It works fine on Desktop, but on my mobile device I get the REQUEST_DENIED status from the callback. Any ideas of how to make it work on mobile devices too?

```
function calculateDistance(origin, destination) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample which reproduces this?

Comment: Can you confirm that Distance Matrix API web service is enabled in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>` in your `info.plist` file of your project.